# Can I wait for a specific background thread finish, then another background thread starts?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Can I wait for a specific background thread finish, then another background thread starts?

Comment: You should accept some of your answers - it will make people happier to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 6):

In .NET 4, you can use Task instead of threads, and then use continuations to achieve your goals:

```
var firstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => PerformSomeLongRunningAction(); );

var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith( t => PerformSecondAction(); );
```

In .NET <=3.5, the options vary.  The best is often to use a WaitHandle to signal your second task.  The first background thread will need to signal the wait handle when it's complete:

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( o =>
      {
           PerformSomeLongRunningAction();
           mre.Set(); // Signal to second thread that it can continue
      });

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( o =>
      {
           mre.WaitOne(); // Wait for first thread to finish
           PerformSecondAction();
      });
```

Comment: I just learned something; today won't be a total waste after all!

Comment: @David: That's nice to hear ;)

Comment: are the created tasks running in a separate thread? It looks like this may just be a more friendly wrapper around the `Thread` stuff.

Comment: @David: Typically, yes.  By default, Tasks are created on threadpool threads.  They provide a lot of advantages, though, especially when working with GUIs, creating MANY tasks, etc - to learn more, see: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Have the first thread launch the second thread, or set some sort of flag telling the hosting app to start the second thread. Of course, I have to ask: if these threads always run sequentially, why create a second thread at all instead of performing all of your work in the first thread?

Comment: "why create a second thread at all" - This is typically true, unless the second thread can do *some* processing prior to the first's completion.  Sometimes, you can do half of your work, but need to wait for results, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

And if you provide more information, we can provide more detail in the answer.

In general, you set up a communication system (a message queue, Event, or delegate) that is used to signal that a process/step/thread is done.  When that happens, start up the next thread.